# Log4j não está gerando log backup

Tags: java, log4j

Tenho dois jar no mesmo classpath, portanto eles estão usando o mesmo log4j.xml.O projeto no qual está o xml, faz o roll corretamente, porém o outro projeto não.

Eu configurei o xml para gerar 10 backup de tamanho 1096K, mas os backups não estão sendo gerado, e o arquivo de log principal é apagado ao atingir o tamanho limite.

log4j.xml:

```
<appender name="CONSOLE" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="[%d{ISO8601}][%-5p][%c.%M()]: %m %n"></param>
    </layout>
    <filter class="org.apache.log4j.varia.LevelRangeFilter">
        <param name="LevelMin" value="DEBUG" />
        <param name="LevelMax" value="FATAL" />
    </filter>
</appender>

<appender name="FILE" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
    <param name="File" value="logs/arqGUI.log" />
    <param name="MaxFileSize" value="4096KB" />
    <param name="MaxBackupIndex" value="10" />
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="[%d{ISO8601}][%-5p][%c.%M()]: %m %n"></param>
    </layout>
    <filter class="org.apache.log4j.varia.LevelRangeFilter">
        <param name="LevelMin" value="DEBUG" />
        <param name="LevelMax" value="FATAL" />
    </filter>
</appender>

<appender name="FILE_SERVICE" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
    <param name="File" value="logs/arqService.log" />
    <param name="MaxFileSize" value="1096KB" />
    <param name="MaxBackupIndex" value="10" />
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="[%d{ISO8601}][%-5p][%c.%M()]: %m %n"></param>
    </layout>
    <filter class="org.apache.log4j.varia.LevelRangeFilter">
        <param name="LevelMin" value="DEBUG" />
        <param name="LevelMax" value="FATAL" />
    </filter>
</appender>

<logger name="com.emp.sin.orcmultemp.service" additivity="false" >
    <level value="WARN" />
    <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
    <appender-ref ref="FILE_SERVICE" />
    <appender-ref ref="FILE_ERR_SERVICE" />
</logger>

<logger name="org.springframework">
    <level value="WARN" />
    <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
    <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
    <appender-ref ref="FILE_ERR" />

</logger>

<logger name="org.hibernate">
    <level value="WARN" />
    <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
    <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
    <appender-ref ref="FILE_ERR" />
</logger>

<root>
    <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
    <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
</root>
```

Utilização do log4j:

```
import org.apache.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

public class MainClass {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger(MainClass.class);
    LOGGER.info("TEST");
}
```